# Need URL for Appstore connectivity and Xcode developer account connectivity

Tags: ios, app-store

In my office, proxy and URL restriction is there so am not able to update the app/softwares through Appstore application and also not able to add the Team, signing certificate in Xcode. I raised the complaint to IT admin and inorder to enable the access they are asking for the URL's.. I searched but no luck .. Can you please share if you know the URL details.

Answer (score 0):

Best to run a network traffic analyser on your computer and make a list of attempted accesses.

Even better, do the same from home (or wherever you have access), and list the actual URLs.

Or (in the mean time) ask/urge IT if they can open HTTPS (and HTTP) access `*.apple.com/*` and `*.itunesconnect.com/*` and see how far you get.

Good luck, this is a very annoying situation I've in too a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Once try below this urls

```
appldnld.apple.com
mesu.apple.com
```

These are for `updates and downloads` of `ios` so i think that it should be same for mac also for appstore downloads or updates!!

And yes you can analyze network traffic as @
meaning-matters mentioned in his answer!

Reference : [How to Stop iOS Software Update Notifications Reminders](http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/04/stop-ios-software-update-notification/)